# Ideas to comments better with python

Tags: python, comments

If you're a python coder you may encounter looking for a way to comments your code better on subcategory code. My meaning by the subcategory code is you may have blocks of codes and then again blocks of codes that relate to the previous block. Here is an example (pay  more attention to comments):

```
# Drink some water to keep your body hydrated:
initialize some parameters

# Choice a glass:
pick up the glass number one
if the glass was dirty:
   wash the dishes  # this would be difficult.

# Pour the glass with water:
while the glass is not filled up:
   pour the glass
```

All I'm saying we are looking for simplicity and when you are in the middle of a code, it's better to know where you are exactly. See the comments again but this time as headers:

```
# h1
initialize some parameters

# h2:
pick up the glass number one
if the glass was dirty:
   wash the dishes

# h2:
while the glass is not filled up:
   pour the glass
```

so when you see the comment `h2`s it would be convenient to know that this part of code is subcode of `h1`:

I used to make the first letter capital as `h1` for comments, and the following code blocks that are related are not capital. Let's wipe out the codes and just focus on the comments:

```
# Drink some water to keep your body hydrated:
... line of codes ...

# choice a glass:
... line of codes ...

# pour the glass with water:
... line of codes ...
```

There are some pros and coins with that:

*pros:*

- Easy to use.

*coins:*

- It doesn't come to the mind right of way.
- If you have more subcategory code this doesn't work.

So I was like "why don't I share this with others to see what they think and what they prefer or use", said it to myself.

Comment: There's no question here: it's just a presentation of some arbitrary conventions for commenting code.

Comment: @chepner It's asking for other peoples Ideas... so like an implicit question

Comment: That's not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

So I was checking something like

```
# H1 comment
# h2 comment
 + easy
 + looks normal in the code.
 - maybe taken up as a mistake
 - only 2 category


# h1 comment
# -- h2 comment
# -- -- h3 comment


# h1 comment
#   h2 comment
#     h3 comment
- looks weird in the code.
```

Note we usually use functions and classed. and this has quit rear use. But they would have a use.
I still prefer -- for the reasons (or no coins).

Answer (score 1):

I usually split my code in python sections:

```
##########  Imports  ##########

##########  Globals  ##########

########## Functions ##########

##########   Main   ###########
```

(I space it equal out with spaces)

And I put comments about functions right before their definition

```
# a random fuction...
def randomfunction()
    pass
```

Comments about code I put behind the code

```
code() # a random example function call
```

Commented out code I delineate from comments this way

```
## commented.out.code()
```